# inferring missing objects

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i begin to do asimple robot that can inferring missing objects on the table like that :[image: image description]

firstly i want to list all i need to do this
1- kinect : can i use any type of kinect or must openni kinect ? or can i use a normal camera ?? why ?

2- the simulation in the picture up is it gazebo ?? how can i link my simulation with reasoning and knowrob ??

3- the relation between my simulation and the picture captuered by my kinect or camera ?

Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45662/inferring-missing-objects/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-10-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-10-11**:
too little info. where do you get this picture?

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-10-11**:
it is a simple target using kinect or camera to just inferring missing component using semantic mapping for objects ,this picture from pdf in semantic

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-10-12**:
this pdf
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?8ujbn5q7gqowk9v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Though inferring the missing objects may appear simple, it is in fact quite a complex problem that requires the integration of perception, knowledge representation and statistical relational models. You can have a look at our paper "[Combining Perception and Knowledge Processing for Everyday Manipulation](http://ias.cs.tum.edu/_media/spezial/bib/iros10kcopman.pdf)" to get an idea of the techniques we have used.

The corresponding ROS packages are comp_missingobj, prolog_perception, mod_probcog, srldb, and the knowrob stack. The experiment was done in early 2010, however, and I am not sure if all components still work in current ROS versions, especially prolog_perception may make problems since we haven't used it in a while. In addition, you will need an object recognition system that can give you the types and positions of objects.

The visualization is not gazebo, by the way, but the visualization module of the knowrob knowledge base (package mod_vis).

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5